# Get WhatsAPI working

Tags: php, codeigniter, whatsapp

Ok, so after a while WhatsAPI has been updated, you should check this new repository:
https://github.com/shirioko/WhatsAPI

I've it actually working, I've registered a number and I can send SMS but when I run the examples.php I can only get responses if I activate the debug to true, if not, everything looks empty.

Even more, the data received comes like "8 byte data" and I can't do anything with it.

Hope someone can help

Comment: taken from the `readme` 

Can I receive chats?

Indeed, using the same socket-receiving mechanism. But you have to parse the incoming data. Parsing functions aren’t included in this release, maybe in the next one?

Answer (score 0):

This has been update to this https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/tree/master/examples

all the best